# Trigger system messages in Microsoft Bot Framework V3

Tags: c#, botframework

In the previous version of the Bot SDK (V1) a message with the text `/deleteprofile` to the Bot Connector would trigger a `Message` of type `DeleteUserData` towards the bot. However, in the new version (V3) this text triggers a simple `Activity` of type `ActivityTypes.Message`. How can I send an `Activity` of type `ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData` to my bot in the new version?

Comment: Can you specify some additional detail around the use case that makes the system message useful to you?

Comment: I used `/deleteprofile` for testing (e.g. resetting dialogs). Strictly speaking I don't need it, because I can implement my own command messages for this, e.g. right now I'm triggering reset with the `>>reset` message. But then the question is: What triggers a message of type `DeleteUserData`?

Comment: We opted to removed this in the V3 schema, given exactly what you described - you can use your own command to manage how to handle data deletion.  As the bot owns the data it stores it can decide how and what data to delete.  We can add this back if it proves to be useful.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BotFramework team opted to removed the "/deleteprofile" command in the V3 schema, given that bot developers can create their own command to manage how to handle data deletion (partial or whole). As the bot owns the data it stores it can decide how and what data to delete. (It can be added back if it proves to be useful.)

Comment: Seems the /deleteprofile command is useful when debugging. Can we add that back?